# file type upload is not working on windows 8 phone?

Tags: php, windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile, windows-phone-8, file-io

what is the alternate of input type file for windows base mobiles,

i can see the browse button but when we touch on browse button nothing work.

Ref to: http://viljamis.com/blog/2012/file-upload-support-on-mobile/

**what is the quick solution to replace input type file **

My Code

```
 <input id="image" name="image" type="file" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't.. Windows Phone does not have file browser accessible to apps